# Draw figure (image) from SVG

Tags: java, android, svg, polygon

I've got SVG file with some structure (it is not defined now). There many points with type of line, radius and degree of angle and many other information about figure (image). There are some information about which lines of figure could resize and etc.
What i have to do with SVG file? How i can parse it and use it to draw path (polygon, shape and etc)?

**UPDATE**: svg-android library it's not exactly what i want, because it gives me drawable from svg file, but my task is a vector image from svg in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Drawable can be either a bitmap or a vector.  The PictureDrawable that svg-android produces is a vector image.  In other words it can be drawn at different scales without pixellation.  It should be perfectly suitable for what you want to do.

Comment: if i convert picturedrawable into bitmap and will resize it, scale it will i loose quality?

Comment: Yes you will.  It won't be a vector any more.

Comment: But i need to resize and scale image without loosing quality, what i have to do? I have to do this actions with picturedrawable instead of creating bitmap from picturedrawable am i right?

Comment: Correct.  Create the PictureDrawable and then draw it using Canvas.drawPicture(Picture) or Picture.draw(Canvas).

Comment: So picturedrawable or picture? I can createPictureDrawable(PictureDrawable object) and getPicture(Picture object) from svg file. Any examples or something else for right ways to scale and resize picture?

Comment: A Picture.  A PictureDrawable is a subclass of Drawable meant to be used with an ImageView.  However, you don't actually describe what your end goal is, so it's possible an ImageView may actually do what you want.  If you are using Picture, you can set the Canvas transformation (with Canvas.scale(), Canvas.translate() etc) before calling Canvas.draw(Picture).

Comment: I want to scale, resize, draw it on canvas and show in imageview with picture without loosing quality of image.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37592/discussion-between-dikkini-and-bigbadaboom)